# How do you change/update a listing image using the Amazon SP-API?

Tags: amazon-selling-partner-api

I've been trying to use the patchListingsItem operation on the Listing Items part of the SP-API (https://github.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-docs/blob/main/guides/en-US/use-case-guides/listings-items-api-use-case-guide/listings-items-api-use-case-guide_2020-09-01.md#tutorial-partially-update-a-listing).

However I don't know exactly how to format the body of the request to change images.

This is the body to update the product title:

```
{
  "productType":"LUGGAGE",
  "patches":[
    {
      "op":"replace",
      "path":"/attributes/item_name",
      "value":[
        {
          "value": "AmazonBasics 16\" Underseat Spinner Carry-On",
          "language_tag": "en_US",
          "marketplace_id": "ATVPDKIKX0DER"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm missing the proper "path" and "value" of the patch request for an image update.

Answer (score 1):

after spending 7 hours looking for solution , here it is for anyone who requires it .

```
host: host,
method: "PATCH",
path: `/listings/2021-08-01/items/${SellerID}/${productSKU}/?marketplaceIds=${marketplaceId}`,
service: "execute-api",
region: "us-east-1",
headers: {
  "x-amz-access-token": `${accessToken}`,
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
},
body: JSON.stringify({
  productType: "PRODUCT",
  patches: [
    {
      op: "replace",
      path: "/attributes/main_product_image_locator",
      value: [
        {
          marketplace_id: marketplaceId,
          media_location:
            "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/XXX.jpg",
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
}),
```

media_location is where you enter your url .

Answer (score 0):

first call get Definitions Product Type
this guide to folow : https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/product-type-definitions-api-v2020-09-01-reference#get-definitions2020-09-01producttypesproducttype
to get response like this :
"propertyGroups": {
"images": {
"title": "Images",
"description": "Indiquez le contenu média, comme les images de produits",
"propertyNames": [
"main_product_image_locator",
"other_product_image_locator_1",
"other_product_image_locator_2",
"other_product_image_locator_3",
"other_product_image_locator_4",
"other_product_image_locator_5",
"other_product_image_locator_6",
"other_product_image_locator_7",
"other_product_image_locator_8",
"swatch_product_image_locator"
]
},

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).